# Sending form with php with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, reactjs

How would one normally go about sending a form from within a ReactJS single page application? I would normally just use POST and send it via php, but now that I am using a single page application I am not quite sure how I could accomplish the same thing. I just want to send a simple email with the contents of that form, that's it.

I have a shared hosting account with php, so i would like to use that and not buy a nodejs server on top of that.

A general, common approach would suffice as an answer.

Comment: In my ReactJS app I'm using ajax to manage api calls. (For me is the most clear way to do it)

Comment: Could I use ajax to send the form contents to my php server and send that email?

Comment: https://github.com/DannyGarciaMartin/react-webpack/blob/master/js/source/comp/AccountForm.jsx this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the exact same thing, craft a POST-Request inside your Javascript and proceed as usual.

```
fetch("/email", {
  method: "POST",
  body: form  //just pass the instance
})
```

Fetch-API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

You would need to have a clickhandler on your form-submit button, which would send the form to your PHP email-service via fetch.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am not sure I understand though. Could you explain a little bit more what I would need to do. Will I need a 3rd party library for this? What is `fetch("/email")` doing here?

Comment: No, `fetch` is the new Javascript Ajax API.

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate your application to two parts: Backend and Frontend.
Your backend should be a REST Full API service and the frontend is your React app. Then you have to call the backend's endpoints from the React with a library like axios.

Read more:

[What exactly is RESTful programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)

https://www.sitepoint.com/best-practices-rest-api-scratch-introduction/

https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios

Comment: So I would need a nodejs server or someting similar? That's what I'm trying to avoid!

Comment: @GeorgeWelder no, you could use any server, PHP is fine.